# Are DM vegan shoes less waterproof than the leather versions?

Tags: clothing, leather

I have a pair of [Dr Martens 1460 Vegan Black shoes](http://www.drmartens.com/uk/p/originals-boots-felix-rub-off-vegan-1460). Every time I wear them in the (not really strong) rain, I get slightly wet feet quickly, mostly at the toes.

Is this normal?

Some years ago I had a pair made of leather and can't remember that they got so easily wet inside.

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic.  What part of this relates to veg*n lifestyle or similar?  You might as well post a question about whether rubber tires are waterproof.

Comment: @Riker I think the question is a bit trivial, but not off-topic because of the reasons you mentioned. If rubber tires were usually non-vegan and had qualities such as good water resistance, it would be, IMO, in scope of this site to ask about their vegan counterparts and their respective qualities.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa this doesn't ask "Are Dr Martens Vegan Black Shoes more waterpoof than normal shoes", it just asks about a quality of those shoes that does not pertain to their vegnness. Heck, I've got similar non-vegan shoes that are horribly non-waterproofed.

Comment: @Riker I am not arguing that the question is good, I don't think it is as it assumes waterproofness based on nothing, however, OP is comparing these shoes to his previous leather shoes and implying these were better. It seems more productive to explain that this is not because those were leather shoes and hence intrinsically better, but rather because things have to be waterproofed to be.. waterproof and that there are ways of achieving that with vegan shoes as well. I am not arguing against closing the question, but against the reason for that. For me, it is triviality, not off-topicness.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I updated the question. For me it is about comparing the vegan version whit the leather one.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa I do not understand why you vote to close questions that you also answer! Questions should be closed if they are not answerable within the format and scope of the site or are duplicates of other questions. IMHO there is almost never a good reason to answer a question that you think should be closed. If answering the question benefits it, then it's extremely unlikely that closing it will also benefit it, because the two things are intended to be mutually exclusive (closing prevents answering) "Too trivial" is not a close reason here.

Comment: @Zanna Yes, you are right. The discrepancy arose by me wanting both to help the OP by answering his question, but when presented with Close/Leave Open vote a couple days later when someone suggested the question for closure, I voted Close because I felt that's better for the site as a whole - partly because I re-evaluated Riker's arguments and found them relevant. As for the "too trivial" part, I might have misinterpreted the "ask specialist questions" guideline.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa OK, I understand. If you want to help OP with a question that should be closed, then I personally suggest commenting accordingly.  Closed questions with accepted or upvoted answers will never be deleted automatically, so it doesn't make much difference whether they are open or closed, except as a vague warning to visitors not to ask questions like this (which arguably has some value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **product page** for the shoes you described **does not mention waterproofness anywhere**. Did a store assistant promise you that they are waterproof? Or do you have any other reason to believe they are? Things usually are not waterproof *by default*.

The product page does not say what the material used is, only that it is synthetic and vegan, and there is quite a good chance that the material simply has worse waterproofing abilities than the leather in your previous pair.

One thing you can do is to **buy an impregnating spray** and impregnate the shoes yourself - it would be good to know the material your shoes are made of though as some of the impregnating products cannot be used on synthetic materials etc.

If the wetness is localised at your toes, this might indicate that there is a certain point or area of entry for the water - try to inspect the shoes for any signs of damage in these parts as this might be covered under your warranty.

While a long shot (since the shoes are probably just not waterproof) but your feet might also get *a bit wet* if the material your shoes are from is not breathable enough and so your feet simply sweat. You don't even have to be warm for this to happen and synthetic materials in general are quite prone to this breathability issue.